# Node js Mongoose query using 'like' and 'concat'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to make the follwoing query with mongoose

i have a customer collection 
with

```
---------- ## Customers ##

 - _id -> someID ,someId
 - fName --> hh , aa
 - lName --> tarik ,tar

----------
```

im trying to get all the customers by name  that starts with 'some text'

input -> tar

output -> all customers that their names start with tar 
1- tarik hh 
2- tar aa

### (combining the fName and lName)

### in SQL

```
select * from customers where fName+' '+lName like @name+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question completely, but since you've separated out the fields by first and last name, you can match them directly with [`db.collection.find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/):

```
> db.test.insert({ fName: 'hh', lName: 'tarik' });
> db.test.insert({ fName: 'foo', lName: 'bar' });

> db.test.find({
  fName: 'hh',
  lName: 'tarik'
});

// Mongo CLI Output
> { "_id" : ObjectId("5d97581bafefcad683e52d37"), "fName" : "hh", "lName" : "tarik" }
```

Comment: its not what im looking for , i need to get all the customers that start with some input i give , take a look at the sql example